# Why child rows on Datatables cannot be shown?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a Datatables like this:
[image]

What I want is if each row is clicked, than it'll expand itself, showing more details (called [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)). I tried following the tutorial on that link, and this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
.elementID {
    color: #dc3545;
    /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc; */
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

td.details-control {
    background: url('../public/img/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.details td.details-control {
    background: url('../public/img/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}

</style>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini" id="Identity-check">
<div class="wrapper">


                    <div class ="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <section class="content">
                          <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-12">

                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header bg-danger back-ops-okp2p">
                                        <h3 class="card-title"><b>History Log</b></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">

                                        <hr style="margin-top:20px;">
                                        <table id="history_log" class="display table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-detail" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsible-detail" style="width:100%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>CRON DATE</th>
                                                    <th>CREATED AT</th>
                                                    <th>UPDATED AT</th>

                                                </tr>
                                                
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>                                           
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showDetail( d ) {
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>Steve Johnson</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>123456</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document.ready).ready(function(){
  var dTable = $('#history_log').DataTable({
            lengthChange: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            searching: true,
            ordering: true,
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('get_all_log') }}",
                data: ''
            },
            paging: true,
            info: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            scrollY: 300,
            scrollX: true,
            columns: 
            [
              /*
            {
                className:      'details-control',
                orderable:      false,
                defaultContent: '<i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"> </ i>',
            },*/
            { data: "date_cron" },
            {data: "created_at" },
            {data: "updated_at" }]
  });


  $('#history_log tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            row.child(showDetail()).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
});


 

</script>
```

Take note at the commented part. If I uncomment that,  I'll get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Which points at  `var dTable = $('#history_log').DataTable({`.
And of course, there no additional column for displaying the +/- icon.

How to fix this?

Comment: Your table is using `serverSide: true` - but if `data: ''` is correct, then it looks as if your JSON response is not following the expected structure of JSON responses for server-side mode.See the [returned data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) section (and the example, later on that same page).

Comment: If that does not help, then can you show us a sample of your JSON - but including the overall structure?

Comment: @andrewjames here's a sample: https://gist.github.com/anta40/9daca0b732fee0285bcdd256ed69b826. By default, each row on DataTables only displays date_cron, updated_at, and created_at. And if you click the row, the rest of the details (detail_1, detail_2 etc) will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the JSON. I realize my `data: ''` comment was wrong - I was confusing the `data` option with `dataSrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some notes regarding the changes I made. After making these changes, the show/hide logic works.

---

1 The sample JSON is not valid JSON. It is missing double-quotes and commas in several places.

Here is the cleaned-up JSON:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 2,
    "recordsFiltered": 2,
    "data": [
    {
        "date_cron": "20210318",
        "created_at": "2021-03-18 17:08:31",
        "updated_at": "2021-03-18 17:08:31",
        "detail_1": "aaaaa",
        "detail_2": "bbbbb",
        "detail_3": "ccccc",
        "detail_4": "ddddd"
    },
    {
        "date_cron": "20210319",
        "created_at": "2021-03-19 00:00:09",
        "updated_at": "2021-03-19 00:00:09",
        "detail_1": "eeeee",
        "detail_2": "fffff",
        "detail_3": "ggggg",
        "detail_4": "hhhhh"
    }
    ]
}
```

---

2 The DataTable is assigned to a variable `dTable` but in the code, this is not used. The code refers to `table`:

```
var row = table.row( tr );
```

I changed these to be consistent.

---

3 Your DataTable expects there to be 4 columns in the HTML table: The 3 in your screenshot, plus one more for the collapse/expand column. Your HTML table has explicitly defined only 3 columns, so I added one more:

```html
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>CRON DATE</th>
        <th>CREATED AT</th>
        <th>UPDATED AT</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Now there is somewhere for your commented-out logic to place its output.